# jQuery navigation re-positioning via css() slow in IE11

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, performance

I realize that there's a lot of people experiencing various jQuery issues in IE.
I have read lots of them but couldn't find a solution for my issue.

My issue can be described as a "laggy" or "jumpy" positioning of a navigation bar that is positioned (via .css() method) relatively to the scroll position.

I haven't had a chance to test in other IE versions, but IE11 (PC) and Chrome (Android Tablet) are two browsers that display the navigation in the right position with a lag.

To see the issue, please open IE11, scroll to the bottom of the page and start scrolling up.
http://dev.vlcek.me/sample6n.html

I am wondering if there's perhaps a better (cleaner) way of coding the desired effect to improve the performance in IE11 and on Android mobile devices.

Thanks for any tips in advance!

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


        var lastScrollTop = 0;
        var curr = 0; 
        var scrollingDown = 0;
        var scrollingUp = 0;

        $(window).scroll(function(event){

                       curr = $(this).scrollTop();

                       if (lastScrollTop < curr){
                            // SCROLLING DOWN
                            $("#status").text('DOWN');

                            scrollingDown = curr;
                            $("#scrollingDown").text("Down: " + scrollingDown);

                       } else{
                            // SCROLLING UP
                            $("#status").text('UP');

                            $("#nav-wrapper").css('position', 'relative');
                            $("#nav-wrapper").css('top',  curr - 100);

                            diff = scrollingDown - curr;
                            if (diff <= 100){
                                $("#diff").text("diff (100): " + diff);
                                $("#nav-wrapper").css('top',  (curr - 100) + diff );
                            }else{
                                $("#diff").text("diff: " + diff);
                                $("#nav-wrapper").css('top',  curr );
                            }


                       }

                    lastScrollTop = curr;

                $("#curr").text('curr: ' + curr);   

        }); // scroll()

    }); // docready
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the top style on the header, why don't you make it `position:fixed` while scrolling up instead? It will give you the same effect, but without the constant css updates and will look right when scrolling in IE.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Joel. Using a fixed position instead of relative has addressed the issue in IE11 (no more jumpy sliding). I still need to test in Chrome on Android tablet (will do tomorrow). I am crossing my fingers. Thanks again!